# Handling OS X signals: no threading available?

Tags: cocoa

I've implemented my own Exception Handler which implements the methods `exceptionHandler:shouldLogException:mask` and `exceptionHandler:shouldHandleException:mask`. Catching the signals works fine but in addition I want to open and read the content of the latest OS X crash report file.

I know that they're stored within `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` folder and I'm able to locate and read the latest.
But: OS X seems to write the crash report AFTER is has terminated the application (and presents the "App has crashed" dialog).

I've tried several ways of threading to "wait" for the current crash report:

- Monitoring the folder using `NSFilePresenter / NSFileCoordinator`
- implementing a `while` loop with GCD to wait
- Using an `NSTimer` which checks for new reports periodically

Nothing of this seems to work. Does anybody have a clue what I can do to wait for the current crash report file? Putting the main thread asleep doesn't help (it just delays the report creation).

Comment: I think you'll find the crash report is just that - so it effectively(1) does not exist until your process has terminated due to a crash . If you are catching the signal then your process has not (yet) crashed, so nothing you do in your *current* process can see it - i.e. a process cannot read its own obituary!  Seek another way to obtain the information you want. HTH. Note (1) "effectively" as the report could be written by library  code after user code has failed to handle the signal and just before the process is terminated.

Comment: Sounds reasonable... thanks, CRD